# Reading glasses with zero correction

Tags: eyeglasses, reading

At an industrial site where I work they recently instituted a policy of wearing protective lenses.  My employer gave us these cheap plastic safety glasses, but they scratch too easily, they fog up all the time, and they're generally uncomfortable.

However, prescription glasses (even those *not* rated for industrial protection) are permitted.  Go figure.  Someone suggested that for those who don't have prescription eyeglasses, then wearing a cheap set of drugstore reading glasses would suffice.

I still have marginally 20/20 vision--I don't need prescription lenses (yet, knock on wood!), but when I tried on the reading glasses with the least correction (+1.25 [diopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioptre), I believe), it still felt annoying.  What I'd really like is a set of cheap glasses with neutral lenses.

My question is this:  Does someone market/sell reading glasses with **zero correction**?  If so, where can I get some?

Comment: I would advise against this -- There are protective eyewear solutions for people with glasses (Usually bigger, bulkier, and much less comfortable than the regular ones, they fit around corrective glasses), but corrective glasses are not typically considered protective eyewear. Depending on your location, by allowing people with prescription glasses to forego safety eyewear your employer could be in serious violation of employee safety laws. The protective eyewear is bigger and seals better to your face for a reason.

Comment: Another tidbit to add to this, if something does get in your eye, the process of removing it will most definitely not leave you with 20/20 vision. For ferrous material they will use magnets to draw the object out -- for other materials it's far less pleasant.

Comment: Tell your boss you can't work with what they gave you.

Comment: I suspect they sell these in costume shops for actors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Googled "zero correction glasses" and got https://www.bleudame.com/clear-glasses as the first hit.  These do appear to be zero correction glasses intended to be stylish.  There are a wide variety of styles available.

Perhaps you could also search for glasses at websites that provide movie props.

Answer (score 3):

Any optician can make a zero correction lens - that's what all their display models are filled with.

All you need to do is pick a frame - or ask about old display frames they no longer need...

Comment: Yes, but that requires an optician.  I was hoping for something already made hanging on a self-serve display stand that I can just run inside the store and purchase.

Comment: ...which would essentially be a very low turnover stock item, how many people need reading glasses with no improvement at all? An optician's might even give you an old set of frames they've no further use for.

Comment: FYI - They are called planar lenses. They are used all the time for cases where only one eye needs correction. The planar lens is used for the eye that does not require correction in a pair of glasses.

Answer (score 3):

Get "visor goggles" - many times more comfortable than normal safety glasses, and can even be worn with corrective lenses.

[image: visor goggles]